# Android - retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I need android 3.5 version dependencies for the following older version.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:convertor-gson:2.3.0
```

Comment: Kindly post minimal code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

these are the latest dependencies for `Retrofit`:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Comment: Thanks  for ur response. I have tried this but it shows unable to resolve dependency for 'app@debug/Compile class path'

Comment: it's because you are using compile in the other dependencies

Comment: use `implementation` instead of `compile` in your `build.gradle (app)`